# Find indexes of items in list of string in an string with Python

Tags: python, string, list, algorithm, indexof

I'm looking for a fast approach to find all the indexes in string which match with items (one or multiple words). Actually I do not need index in list I need index in string.

I have a list of words and an string like these:

```
words = ['must', 'shall', 'may','should','forbidden','car',...]
string= 'you should wash the car every day'

desired output:
[1,4]# should=1, car=4
```

The length of list some times can be more than hundreds of items and string more that tens of thousands.

I'm looking for a so fast approach because it is called a thousand times in each iteration.

I know how to implement it with loops and check all the items one-by-one but it's so slow!

Comment: can words have duplicate elements?

Comment: @AnuragWagh No they can not

Comment: @Sina Check my answer and see if it fits your requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is make `words` `set` instead of `list` and then do simple list comprehension:

```
words = {'must', 'shall', 'may','should','forbidden','car'}
string= 'you should wash the car every day'

out = [i for i, w in enumerate(string.split()) if w in words]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 4]
```

Comment: it works but it's so slow, that why I mentioned I know how to implement it with loops but its so slow

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Aho Corasick](https://cp-algorithms.com/string/aho_corasick.html) algorithm to this.

Given a set of strings and a text, it finds occurrences of all strings from the set in the given text in `O(len+ans)`, where `len` is the length of the text and `ans` is the size of the answer.

It uses an automaton and can be modified to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionaries 
time complexity for look up dictionary is O(1)

```
string = 'you should wash the car every day'

wordToIndex = {word: index for index, word in enumerate(string.split())}

words = ['must', 'shall', 'may','should','forbidden','car']

result = [wordToIndex[word] for word in words if word in wordToIndex]

# [1,4]
```

Comment: Should note that dictionary operations are O(n) worst-case and O(1) expected.

Comment: You're assuming that the words in the list won't be a subsequence of the words in the string. `"Let's play football"`, `["foot","ball"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension,

```
print([string.split().index(i) for i in string.split() if i in words]) 
#[1,4]
```